# IE sends different origin for CORS request according to protocol

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a CORS setup that is failing in IE. IE works in an HTTP environment where it sends an:

```
Origin: null
```

header on a 302. However in an HTTPS environment it sends:

```
Origin: https://www.example.com
```

My API is wrapped with an action filter that simply reflects back the origin and in all other browsers and for IE in non https environments this works.

However in HTTPS IE fails, stating:

> SEC7120 : Origin null not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
>
> script 7002 XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is
>   denied.

It's not getting back null because it's not sending null as the origin. All other browsers just send null regardless of the protocol.

So does anyone know where IE behaviour in the two different protocols has been defined. It seems there is a mismatch between what it sends and what it expects back.